# VistaSwitcher exclusions - window title wildcards

Tags: alt-tab

I'd like to exclude all Firebug windows from alt-tab menu in VistaSwitcher. If I add a new exclusion and only use the `process name` parameter, I'll exclude all Firefox windows. So I'd like to narrow it down using the `window title` parameter. All Firebug window titles start with "Firebug" but then there's some information about the current Firefox tab. So a wildcard would be useful. I tried

`Firebug*`
`Firebug.*`
`Firebug%`

but none worked. Is there a way to do it without adding every possible Firebug title to the exclusion list?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround pretty quickly. Using AutoHotkey I can force the window title to always be just "Firebug":

```
SetTimer FbVistaSwitcher, 50

FbVistaSwitcher:
    WinSetTitle Firebug,, Firebug
return
```

and then in VistaSwitcher I can simply exclude "Firebug"

I'm not going to mark this as the answer for a few days, perhaps someone has a better solution.